# How to subset matrix with couples of row.name and col.name

Tags: r

I have a simple problem.  I have a data frame with two columns of character variables, corresponding to row and column name "couples" from a separate matrix. I just want to use those couples to look up values in the matrix, returned in a vector.

I'm sure it is trivial, but I haven't been able to come across an answer in over an hour of googling.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
m <- as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), 
                          b=c(14,15,16,17), 
                          c=c(27,28,29,30), 
                          d=c(43,44,45,46)))
row.names(m) <- c('w','x','y','z')

df <- data.frame(j=c('x','z','z','w','x'),
                 k=c('a','b','d','d','c'))

#I just want to "lookup" a vector of values equal to c(2,17,46,43,28)
result <- sapply(df, function(x) m[x[1],x[2]])

result
j.c k.b 
28  14
```

Can someone help me figure this out?  `sapply` may not be the best approach, and I'm open to other ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just coerce the `data.frame` to be a `matrix` and use it as index

```
> m[as.matrix(df)]
[1]  2 17 46 43 28
```

Take a look at [this document](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing-matrices-and-arrays) to realize why this works.

Comment: vergilcw, you may also have a look at `?Extract`. In the section 'Matrices and arrays' you will find: "Indexing via a character matrix with one column per dimensions is also supported if the array has dimension names. As with numeric matrix indexing, each row of the index matrix selects a single element of the array". Thanks @Jilber - I learned I new way to subset. +1!

Comment: Thanks, Jilber!  That solved my issue.  Henrik, thanks also for the comment.  It is nice to know I can pass character vectors individually as well if the matrix has dimension names.